# if the class is private , how many java file will be needed?

Tags: java

A friend asked me this riddle like java question. can anyone help me in this...

If we want to create 50 classes whose access is public, 50 interfaces whose access is public and 50 classes whose access is default, the minimum number of .java files required is  ?
like this code...

```
public class A{}
private interface B{}
class C{}
```

And i'm interested in further study about this .java files needed. any pointer or reference to any material will be helpful :)

Comment: The limit is one *public* class per file.  You can declare all three in your example (a public class, a package-scope class, and an interface) all in the same file.

Comment: Just **ONE** .java file is enough. You can define public class and public interface inside a class as inner class. That means in one public class you can define the remaining 49 public class and 50 public interface as inner class. And the remaining 50 default classes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have only one public class/interface in a single .java file. (but you can have many non public classes/interfaces in same .java file)
therefore
you need 50 .java files for your 50 public classes
another 50 .java files for 50 public interfaces
other classes can be put in any of the above 100 classes.
I think minimum number of .java files that you need is 100

Comment: Just **ONE** .java file is enough. You can define public class and public interface inside a class as inner class. That means in one public class you can define the remaining 49 public class and 50 public interface as inner class. And the remaining 50 default classes.